# AppBarLayout Toolbar TabLayout ViewPager DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I want to use a DrawerLayout in combination with a ViewPager which is connected to a TabLayout. On top I want the Toolbar.

This code brings the best results however, when the drawer is open it hides the toolbar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"

            android:paddingTop="0dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"


            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

        <com.sourcecastle.commons.controls.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="?attr/theme_background_color"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"

        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="00:00:00"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDistance"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:text="123km"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llMap"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/speedFragment"
                class="com.sourcecastle.logbook.fragments.SpeedFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:layout_weight=".60" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/mMap"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".40" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEnlarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/enlarge"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]

I already tried almost all combinations and read a lot of posts. Also the simmilar question here:
[Android CoordinatorLayout + TabLayout + ViewPager Toolbar not hidding on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36896082/android-coordinatorlayout-tablayout-viewpager-toolbar-not-hidding-on-scroll)

When I bring out the AppBarLayout and leave the ViewPager in the DrawerLayout the ViewPager is unter the TabLayout and Toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To this Linear Layout give top margin of the height of your toolbar

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="?attr/theme_background_color"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: Man ^^ It was that easy and I spent hours on it :( However, your answer is not 100% correct. It is: android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"

Comment: yeah you are right. padding will show background color of the layout and marginTop will not. I forgot that.